# How to re-order the .wav file channels

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I need to change the order of channels in .wav file. for example if .wav file contains 16 channel like

> "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16"

then need to change this order to

> "14 15 16 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the channelmap filter for this,

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af "channelmap=13|14|15|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12" out.wav
```

Channel index starts from 0.